# Python MySQL query issue: "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

using a python script running in a Flask webapp I execute a simple select query on a table of the
connected database (I'm using the mysql python connector library)

```
import mysql.connector

...


    stmt = "SELECT * FROM %s"

    try:
        self.cur.execute(stmt % table)
        print('stmt executed')
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        print('result fetched')
    except Exception as ex:
        self.handle_closure(ex, error=True)  # function for handling exceptions
        return -1
```

The issue is that the execution of this code on a particular table raises the exeption mentioned
in the title: "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes".
The same function works well on a different table

in the stdout "stmt executed" gets printed while "result fetched" doesn't

Thank you

PS. adding the query used to create the table since it may be usefull to know the schema of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `aaa` INT NOT NULL,
  `bbb` CHAR(15),
  `ccc` TIME,
  `ddd` TIME
);

ALTER TABLE xxx
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint
FOREIGN KEY (aaa) REFERENCES yyy(id);
```

Comment: Does either of the `TIME` columns contain `00:00:00` values? I've seen the exact same error with a friend's project, and it only affected rows where a `TIME` column was `00:00:00`

Comment: @LukasThaler This is exactly what happened with my code as well.